# Why is the unit circle traversed clockwise for the Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-transform

For a signal $x$, the Fourier transform is defined as:

$$\mathcal{F}\{x(t)\} = F(j \omega) = \int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} x(t) e^{-j \omega t}  \,dt$$

We can see the signal $x$ as a sum of periodic signals of different frequencies. The $e^{-j \omega t}$ factor inside the integral acts as sort of an "indicator" or "scanner" so as for the Fourier transform for a certain frequency $\omega$ to reflect the weight (in physical terms, the amplitude) of the periodic constituent of that frequency in the makeup of $x$.

My question is, why make add the $-$ and make the angle vary clockwise instead of respecting the usual convention of making it vary counterclockwise? Is there any logical or historical reason for this?

Comment: Another informal way of looking at it is as the inner product of the function $x$ with the complex function $t \mapsto e^{i \omega t}$, and the inner product is defined as $\langle a,b \rangle = \int a(t) \overline{b(t)} dt$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point is that to detect a "signal" $e^{j\omega t}$ that goes counterclockwise at rate $\omega$, you multiply it by $e^{-j\omega t}$ (making it constant) and integrate.

Comment: I'm amazed at how straightforward it is actually, this makes a lot of sense...